# Mixing MDX Drillthrough statement and SQL joins

Tags: sql, mdx

I want to use an MDX drill through command but i also want to join it to some SQL tables as well.

that is there will be an Id in the fact table and not a lot of other data I want to join this on to another table or view  and produce a report based on those ID's returned in the drill down.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

MDX won't do this directly.  The only way I can think of doing this would be to retrieve the recordset from the drillthrough (which can be done with ADO), load it into a temporary table and join it against whatever else you want in a query.

The other option is to widen the drillthrough (if the dimensions have the data you need) and get the fields from that.  Note that SSAS2005+ can support multiple drillthrough actions.

[This MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140054%28office.10%29.aspx) has some code snippets that demonstrate working with record sets returned from a drillthrough.